# Redirect subpages to parent-directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all requests for subpages to the directory root. Unfortunately I only get redirect loops. Here is a sample of my .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^parent-directory/.*$ /parent-directory [L,R=301]
```

Although I understand why there is a redirection loop I can’t think of a working solution despite searching for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.* means 0 o more characters of any type

Use .+ to make it 1 or more and discard /parent-directory redirecting onto itself

Comment: Thank you for your answer ezra-s! Although it did not work out the way you described it, the hint with wildcard-characters helped! 
My mod_rewirte-Module now looks similar to this and it works: 
`RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^parent-directory/.+$ /parent-directory [L,R=301]` Most important: No more redirect loops! Thx!

Comment: Just an additional sidenote, using $ after a .+ or .* is futile. Glad you solved it! :)

Comment: In fact, instead of `.+$` you can simply use `.` (a single dot). And something like `.*$` can be omitted altogether. (One would assume that the "directory root" is `/`, not `/parent-directory`?)